# Sql filter - Use AND and OR operator in filter on multiple columns

Tags: oracle

I need to pull data for
business=IT and
Date >= 2021-07-01 and date<= 2022-09-10

Either any of the conditions satisfy I need to pull
Modifier: G11, G7
Service: phys, oper

```
Technology modifier Date      service
IT.          95.    2021-07-01.  Phys
Cse.         G5.    2021-09-09.  Tec
Mech.        GT.    2022-08-07.  Tec
IT.          G11.   2022-09-06.  Tec
IT.          G7.    2022-08-07.  Oper
IT.          GR.    2022-06-26.  Tec
```

Technology  modifier Date      Service
IT.         95.    2021-07-01.   Phy
IT.         G11.    2022-09-06   Tec
IT.         G7.     2022-08-07.  Oper

Below is what I tried:

Where
Technology= 'IT'
AND
(date  between '2021-07-01' and '2022-09-10')
OR
(Modifier IN ('G11', 'G7'))
OR
(Service In ('phys', 'oper'))

Problem here is it is pulling all the other technologies too. How do I modify  so that it pulls the correct info.

Comment: Can you share the expected result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
where
    technology = 'IT' and
    ("Date"  between '2021-07-01' and '2022-09-10') and
    (
        (modifier IN ('G11', 'G7')) or
        (service In ('phys', 'oper'))
    )
```

Answer (score 1):

`AND` has higher operator precedence than `OR` if you want `OR` to be treated as if it has higher operator precedence then wrap the `OR` conditions in brackets:

```sql
WHERE  Technology= 'IT'
AND    "Date" BETWEEN DATE '2021-07-01' AND DATE '2022-09-10'
AND    (  Modifier IN ('G11', 'G7')
       OR Service  IN ('phys', 'oper')
       )
```

*Note: `Date` is a reserved word and cannot be used as an unquoted identifier. If you want to use it as an identifier (please don't, its bad practice) then you will need to use a quoted identifier (and the correct case).*

*Note 2: `'2021-07-01'` is not a date, it is a string literal that happens to look like a date. Assuming that your `Date` column has the `DATE` data type then Oracle will try to be helpful and implicitly convert your string literal to a `DATE` but that relies on the `NLS_DATE_FORMAT` session parameter and any user can change that parameter in their own session at any time so you should not rely on implicit conversions. Instead, use a `DATE` literal or explicitly use the `TO_DATE` function, with a format model, to perform the conversion.*

Comment: Thank you MT0. This answer works as well. Date column name was just an example I created. I have different column name for date.